# XML Schema regex empty string

Tags: regex, xml, xsd, xmllint

I have a XML Schema with a regex restriction that matches three different options and looks similar to this:

```
somestring|someotherstring|
```

1. Some string, or
2. Some other string, or
3. Empty string

**My problem is that xmllint does not like this regex.** It gives the following error:

> regexp error : failed to compile: expecting a branch after |

I am forced to comply with xmllint because of the environment.

**My question is, what are other options to match empty string using regex in a XSD?**

As I understand, negative look ahead is not available in a XSD regex, and I am at a loss for other options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use an optional group:

```
(somestring|someotherstring)?
^                          ^^
```

It will match these 2 words or an empty string. In XSD, all patterns are anchored automatically, so, no additional operators are necessary.

See what the [regex matches](https://regex101.com/r/nR1zT0/1).

Comment: This works for me, and I hope there are more answers given.

Answer (score 3):

I think Wiktor's answer is fine (+1), but you asked for more answers, so here are some alternatives:

### Regex Solutions

**Works with Xerces-J *but not* xmllint:**

```
|somestring|someotherstring
somestring||someotherstring
somestring|someotherstring|
```

**Works with Xerces-J *and* xmllint:**

```
(somestring|someotherstring)?    <!-- Wiktor's answer -->
()|somestring|someotherstring
somestring|()|someotherstring
somestring|someotherstring|()
```

### Non-regex Solution

**Works with Xerces-J *and* xmllint:**

```
 <xs:simpleType>
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
     <xs:enumeration value=""/>
     <xs:enumeration value="somestring"/>
     <xs:enumeration value="someotherstring"/>
   </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: I like this one as well: somestring|someotherstring|(), it should have been obvious.